# ES6 Class Property Definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

So I've read around stackoverflow. In ES6 this is invalid:

```
class MyClass {
   myProperty = "";

   constructor() {
       this.myProperty = "Hey";
   }
}
```

But it is valid in ES7.

However, is this valid:

```
class MyClass {
    setViewModel(viewModel) {
        this.internalViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    get viewModel() { return this.internalViewModel }
}
```

Here I haven't defined `internalViewModel` until I've actually set it. I expect that if you haven't called `myClass.setViewModel(something)` before you call `myClass.viewModel`, you will get `undefined` returned from `myClass.viewModel`.

Is this correct?

If you have this ES7 class and you tried to access `myProperty` like so `myClass.myProperty` would you get the expected `"Hey"` or not?

Comment: Actually it's not valid in ES7 either, but might become valid in ES8.

Comment: Class properties are not part of ES7.

Comment: [The proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) is actually a [stage 0 proposal](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this ES6 correct?

Yes.

Although it might be considered a bad practise not to create all properties in the constructor.

> If you have this ES7 class and you tried to access `myProperty` like so `myClass.myProperty` would you get the expected `"Hey"` or not?

Yes, but notice that `myProperty` is not a class but an instance property.

```
var myClass = new MyClass;
myClass.myProperty; // "Hey"
```

Also, the instance field declaration with the initialiser is totally superfluous anyway, because it's overwritten right away through the near-equivalent `this.myProperty = "Hey";`.