# What do var-less variables mean within TypeScript classes?

Tags: typescript, angular, variable-declaration

When creating a component class in Angular2. Why don't we need `var`? when declaring a new variable? eg:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My title';
}
```

How come it is not `var title = 'My title';` instead?

EDIT: My original question comes when I was reading [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html), where the original code looked like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

Comment: If you've seen an example using this, there *may* have been minimal scopes involved. It's best practice to use `var` or in your case `const` & `let` to define your variables, unless you're overwriting an existing variable.

Comment: @Seth  Hmm... because I'm just looking through angular 2's documentations [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and they've never used the '`var`' tag under `export class` :/

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that was a class. I'll elaborate below

Comment: That's not an ES2015 class. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35468538/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi It is Typescript right? I think someone edited my original title..

Comment: That is an ES2015 class if using the proposed spec through the stage-1 plugin that babel provides. Check this out https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2&code=class%20AppComponent%20%7B%0A%20%20title%20%3D%20'My%20title'%3B%0A%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a TypeScript (and proposed ES2015) shorthand sugar for setting instance variables for the `AppComponent` object type. Those differ from an actual scoped variable within JavaScript.

Currently this feature is in the proposal stage for ES2015. However since TypeScript is its own language, which is a strict superset of ES, it implements most all of the proposed ESnext standards. The caveat to using this with Babel is that you're required to include the stage-1 plugin (or use a different transpiler that includes this specific ES proposition). But since this is just that, a proposal, it's not standard outside of TypeScript.

This example's [vanilla JavaScript counterpart](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20AppComponent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20title%20%3D%20'Tour%20of%20Heroes'%3B%0D%0A%20%20hero%20%3D%20'Windstorm'%3B%0D%0A%7D) translates to:

```js
function AppComponent() {
  this.title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  this.hero = 'Windstorm';
}

var appComponent = new AppComponent();
console.log(appComponent);
console.log(appComponent.title);
console.log(appComponent.hero);
```

**Note:** Since Angular2 traditionally uses TypeScript, it's helpful to have an [online transpiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) handy if you choose to use TypeScript in favor of the alternatives.

Comment: So it's typescript, not ES6?

Comment: I think I understand what you're alluding to. Currently it's typescript-only unless you use the `stage-1` plugin with babel (or a different transpiler that includes current ES propositions). But since this is just that, a proposal, it's not standard outside of TypeScript. But the TypeScript language implements most of the proposed ESnext standards.

Comment: Yes, please emphasise that in your answer. I can also reopen the question if you want

Comment: Yes please, If you don't mind. I just cast a nomination to do so.